# How do I configure SAMBA to use ADS & SMBPASSWD authentication?

Tags: authentication, samba, likewise-open

I'm using Beyond Trust to integrate with active directory on a CentOS 5.6 server.  I'm using the interop-install that comes with Beyond Trust to configure SAMBA, which works fine.  However, I have some local accounts that I want to still work & for policy reasons, I can't create them in AD.  Is there a way to configure SAMBA to use both authentication methods, or use ADS as primary & fall back on SMBPASSWD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **smb.conf** you can specify the '**auth methods**' parameter, listing which authentication methods you want to use, such as:

```
auth methods = guest sam winbind
```

The parameters are read left to right; with the example above, Samba will try to match the username with the local smbpasswd first **before** going trying to match AD.

Note that you may want to replace **sam** with **sam_ignoredomain** depending on your version of Samba and the format of your username. Play around with what works for you.

http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#AUTHMETHODS

Comment: I used `auth methods = sam winbind` which works.  I'm posting my working smb.conf in an answer below just for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with:

```
[global]    
        workgroup = DOMAIN
        security = ADS
        auth methods = sam winbind
        realm = DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.COM
        machine password timeout = 0
        server string = SERVER
        idmap domains = ALL
        idmap config ALL:backend = lwicompat_v4
        idmap config ALL:default = yes
        idmap config ALL:readonly = yes
        idmap uid = 10000-33554431
        idmap gid = 10000-33554431
```

Everything else is vanilla SAMBA config.